# How do I match the slash at the end of an xml string?

Tags: .net, xml, regex

**The Problem:**
I want to match a certain xml substring (see below ex. A) using Regex. The problem is that I can’t match the slash at the end of xml string because its a meaningful char in Regex. I even tried to escape the slash by inserting a backslash before the slash in my pattern (see code below) but still couldn’t make it to work...

**The Question:**
How the heck do I make .NET Regex match the slash at the end of the xml string??? Need some of you code ninjas to help me. Thanks in advance for your help, my friend.

**The Input:**

```
<SummarySection id="_470">
   <Title>Statistics</Title> 
   <Para id="_331"> Note: Estimated new cases in the United States in 2010:<Reference refidx="1"/> </Para>  
</SummarySection>
```

**The Code**:

```
// ex A: Pattern need to match (<Reference refidx="1"/>)

string xnodeptn = @"(<Reference refidx=""[a-zA-Z0-9]""/>)";  
Regex refregex = new Regex(xnodeptn, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection mymatches = refregex.Matches(xe.ToString());
foreach (Match mch in mymatches)
{
...
}

string xnodeptn = @"(<Reference refidx=""[a-zA-Z0-9]""\/>)";
```

Comment: Please don't add things like "(.NET Regex)" to your titles. We use tags for that purpose on [so].

Comment: Hmmm... Thats a hard one my friend...Maybe someone here who is really smart can answer it...

Comment: Put the input into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a slash "/" [is not a reserved character in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). So I think there must be a different problem with the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`@"(<Reference refidx=""[a-zA-Z0-9]""/>)"` Works just fine!!!
Try running this:

```
string text = "<SummarySection id=\"_470\"> <Title>Statistics</Title> <Para id=\"_331\"> Note: Estimated new cases in the United States in 2010: <Reference refidx=\"1\"/> </Para> <ItemizedList id=\"_332\" Style=\"bullet\"> </SummarySection>";         
string xnodeptn = @"(<Reference refidx=""[a-zA-Z0-9]""/>)";  
Regex refregex = new Regex(xnodeptn, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection mymatches = refregex.Matches(text);
foreach (Match mch in mymatches)
{
    MessageBox.Show(mch.ToString());
}
```

It returns the match in the sample text (`<Reference refidx=\"1\"/>`). Try looking for another problem or post more of your code.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I did try, but it is not returning me any match, mymatches.Count is 0!!!!

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with xe.toString() ... I can't tell from the code what xe is. Any details?

Comment: @Nazo I wouldn't be surprised if there's whitespace between the attribute and the closing / in the real input, which would prevent this from matching. That's easy to fix, but it's yet another example of why trying to parse XML with a regex is usually a bad idea.

Comment: yes, that was the exact problem whitespace between the attribute and the closing solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as Reddog says, "/" is not a special character in regular expressions. If it were, you could escape it with a backslash, but you don't need to.

Secondly, why are you using regular expressions to process XML? Do you really want to process `<Reference refidx="1"/>` differently from `<Reference refidx="1"></Reference>`? If you do, then there's something fishy going on - you're not using XML as it was designed to be used: these two constructs are supposed to be equivalent.

Comment: Michael, thanks, yes it wasnt special character but I just thought it that way because it wasnt working, I am no using regular expressions to process XML, I am using Linq XML, but I just needed to match this in my xhtml data with regex.

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers was correct, it was something else causing the pattern to not work, in my XML there is not space before closing tag as follow `<Reference refidx="1"/>` but my Regex pattern was expecting an space to match before the closing tag as the following: `<Reference refidx="1" />` not sure why is like that but my issue is solved.